# How to provide arguments for a method that claims to not accept arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api

The [Google Calendar API docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events) state that to create an event, you pass in a number of key/value pairs, which works for me:

```
event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new{
  summary: 'Google I/O 2015',
  location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  description: 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.'
} # truncated
```

What I'd like to do is build the hash ahead of time, as I'm not sure whether or not there will be a description:

```
event_info = {summary: 'Google I/O 2015',
  location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103'}

if description_text:
  event_info["description"] = description_text
end

event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(event_info)
```

but this gives me the error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

The docs don't give more info and I don't see how the `.new` method doesn't require arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can actually do what you're asking, but you could do this:

```rb
def event description_text
    description = nil
    description = description_text if description_text
    # Any other conditional logic

    Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
        summary: 'Google I/O 2015'
        location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103'
        description: description
    )
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [“double splat” operator, `**` to convert a hash into keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion). In your case it will look something like this:

```
event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(**event_info)
```

Comment: Although looking at those Google docs it’s not clear what’s going on. I think @mahemoff is right and the example is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The call you're making above is the same as this:

```
event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new
{ summary: 'Google I/O 2015', ... }
```

In other words, the argument is being passed in at all, it's just a hash doing nothing, which explains why you get `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`.

Looking at the docs, Google's Ruby example seems to be in error. I would try replacing the curly braces with `(` and `)`. i.e.:

```
event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
  summary: 'Google I/O 2015',
  location: '800 Howard St.,
  ...
)
```

(You could also do ({ ... }) but it's unnecessary as the {} are implicit here.)

That should hopefully work, assuming the rest of the example is valid Ruby.

Comment: Your example works, but I can't see how I can add the optional `description`